# Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute on Except operation

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am trying to remove some rows from my `DataTable` `dt` in a loop where I get the above Exception:

```
while (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && retry < Globals.PushRetryLimit)
{
    var query = dt.AsEnumerable().Except(successBatch.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default)
            .AsEnumerable().Except(failBatch.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);
    if (dt.AsEnumerable().Any())
        dt = query.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

`successBatch` and `failBatch` are both `DataTable` clones of `dt`.

In the other questions where this error has been asked, we are dealing with a `foreach` loop. Why does this error occur?

**Stacktrace:**

```
   at System.Data.DataTableExtensions.LoadTableFromEnumerable[T](IEnumerable`1 source, DataTable table, Nullable`1 options, FillErrorEventHandler errorHandler)
   at System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Comment: It's not about the `foreach` loop, it's about the fact that the enumerable is being iterated over **while a change in the data happens**, apparently in those other question by a `foreach` loop. Here you are also iterating.

Comment: @GrantWinney OK, how can I replace my `dt` so that it's the one that remains from the `Except()` operation?

Comment: Try to add a `.ToArray()` after each `.AsEnumerable()` to break the deferred execution.

Comment: How are `successBatch` and `failBatch` defined?

Comment: What if you assign `dt.Rows.Count` to an int at each loop and compare the int in the `while`?

Comment: On which line is the exception thrown? Can you show the full stacktrace?

Comment: @Maarten the last line. For some reason now I get an `InvalidOperationException` that says:  "The source contains no DataRows."

Comment: This error happens if your variable _query_ doesn't contain any row. (Is it possible that you have removed all rows?) Just add a check for Count before calling CopyToDataTable

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the elements in the collection (your dataTable) while looping over it with foreach.

Foreach queries the enumerator and asks for the next element. If you remove an item the enumerator's state becomes invalid. An enumerator has to store some date indicating where its current position.

You should not do this. Maybe use another collection to keep track of changes or use [concurrent collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (read about the classes in the link)

Comment: But he's *not* mutating the collection during the query, at least not with any of the code shown.

Comment: @Sevry but he so is, ``var dt = query...`` followed by ``var query = dt...``

Comment: @Zache That is not mutating the collection, he is creating a new datatable, and assigning that to the variable. The underlying collection of the original datatable is not mutated.