# Clean a DataTable in a loop moving used items to two other DataTables

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a main `DataTable` called `dtMain` and two child DataTables `dtSuccess` and `dtFail`. In a while loop that has a 10 second delay in each iteration some items in `dtMain` will be added to `dtSuccess` and `dtFail`.
So in each iteration I would like my `dtMain` to be clean from everything that is in those other two lists.

I will put the code I have tried here but unfortunately it does not work.

```
while (dtMain.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   var query = dt.AsEnumerable().Except(dtSuccess.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default)
                 .AsEnumerable().Except(dtFail.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);
   if (dtMain.AsEnumerable().Any())
        dtMain = query.CopyToDataTable();
   Thread.SLeep(10000);
}
```

I have received Exceptions such as:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute

And `InvalidOperationException`

> The source contains no DataRows

Comment: It seems that I can't reproduce your problem. Tried with three table with the same structure and this code works as expected. Do you have some code parts not included in your sample above?

Comment: at what condition data from dtMain will go to tdSuccess and what condition will go to tdFail

Comment: Pretty much the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646059/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-might-not-execute-on-except-opera you just added some extra details. Why not update the other question instead of asking it again?

Comment: @Maarten which was asked by myself and I didn't get any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you modifying the dtSuccess and dtFail datatables in another thread?  You'll need to use a synchronization technique to only allow one thread in at a time.

To be honest, datatables aren't a very good mechanism for this.  In fact, I rarely find datatables to be a good solution.  One such solution might be to stop using the dtMain datatable, and convert it to a `ConcurrentQueue<DataRow>`.  Have your other thread(s) pull from the Queue, and the main thread can just check to see if TryPeek on the queue fails.  Or use a ReaderWriter lock to synchronize access to dtMain.

Answer (score 0):

try looping on a variable (This will solve your collection modified problem) :

```
int i = dtMain.Rows.Count ;

while ( i > 0)
{
   var query = dt.AsEnumerable().Except(dtSuccess.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default)
                 .AsEnumerable().Except(dtFail.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);
   if (dtMain.AsEnumerable().Any())
        dtMain = query.CopyToDataTable();
   Thread.SLeep(10000);
   i = dtMain.Rows.Count ;
}
```